# Is it possible to create a dashboard with several pages using Panel in Python, and how can I achieve this?

Tags: python, panel, dashboard

I'm trying to create an interactive Dashboard, thus I chose Panel. Seing galleries of dashboards, on the sidebar I couldn't help but see people managed to create a Dashboards with more than 1 "page". On the sidebar there are clickable buttons that once clicked on display another dashboard, here is an example :
[text](https://awesome-panel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_copy_of_project_root/README.html)
(the first one of the internet page)
On the guides i followed, when you create a panel dashbard, the layout is as follows:

```
layout = FastListTemplate( title = [], Sidebar = [], main =[])
```

Is there a way to create more than one "main"? Or is there another way than "FastListTemplate" to create the dashbord?

I tried to find a tutorial showing the creation of a dashboard but none was multipage and i couldn t manage to find a code sample of a multipage dashboard.